# What is the Usage of Android Super Class?

Tags: android

friends,

any one guide me what is the purpose of Super class in android i have seen in many
@Override methods. for example

```
@Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(final Object... args) 
         {   super.onProgressUpdate(args);
}

@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
}

@Override     
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If your override methods only look like that, you should not be overriding them at all. Only override when you need to alter or add functionality to a method.

Comment: Take a look at Raghav Sood's answer and comment under it. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14671985/1808829) He explained very clearly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Using the Keyword super](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Briefly: if you override some method (*onProgressUpdate*,..) in your class but want to use original one from parent class you use *super* keyword.

I recommend you using *super* as in example to prevent breaking parent class logic.

Comment: But I see people using it without @override. What is the importance of super with or without override?

Answer (score 4):

The superclass of a class is the class that the class was extended from, or null if it wasn't extended.

for example, say you have a class called *object*, containing an *onDestroy()* method.
If you then make a class based on *object*, called *textbox*, that extends(inherits) *object*, and thus has all the methods found in *object*. If you have no *onDestroy()* specifically for *textbox*, the *onDestroy()* inherited from *object* would get called, if you create your own *onDestroy()* to override the one from *object* that one will be called instead.

To make sure you are not missing important functionality that should come with *textbox* being an *object*, such as correct memory management when destroying the class, it's important to also do what would be done for an *object*, not only what you want to do for your *textbox*, this is done by calling the *super.onDestroy()*, which in this case would essentially call *object.onDestroy()*.

Answer (score 2):

in super class many hardware interaction, memory management codes are written which are necessary for performing these function so if you override any method then u can write your own codes and let the other complexity handles by super class of android

Comment: Wow... Way to make it way more complicated than it really is without answering the question.