# super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Tags: android, instance, super, oncreate

I have created an Android Application Project and in MainActivity.java > `onCreate()` it is calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`.

As a beginner, can anyone explain what is the purpose of the above line?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Every Activity you make is started through a sequence of method calls. `onCreate()` is the first of these calls.

Each and every one of your Activities extends `android.app.Activity` either directly or by subclassing another subclass of `Activity`.

In Java, when you inherit from a class, you can override its methods to run your own code in them. A very common example of this is the overriding of the `toString()` method when extending `java.lang.Object`.

When we override a method, we have the option of completely replacing the method in our class, or of extending the existing parent class' method. By calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`, you tell the Dalvik VM to run your code **in addition** to the existing code in the onCreate() of the parent class. If you leave out this line, then **only your code** is run. The existing code is ignored completely.

However, you must include this super call in your method, because if you don't then the `onCreate()` code in `Activity` is never run, and your app will run into all sorts of problem like having no Context assigned to the Activity (though you'll hit a `SuperNotCalledException` before you have a chance to figure out that you have no context).

In short, Android's own classes can be incredibly complex. The code in the framework classes handles stuff like UI drawing, house cleaning and maintaining the Activity and application lifecycles. `super` calls allow developers to run this complex code behind the scenes, while still providing a good level of abstraction for our own apps.

Comment: one more question - when we override the parent class method then does this derived method still hold the code of parent class method, or it is a new fresh method?

Comment: If you call super, the code of the parent method is put where the super call is. If super is not called, it is a fresh method.

Comment: Raghav Sood, I think you should add your comment text to the answer since it explains the usage of super method more understandably for beginners. At least I understood it only from your comment :)

Comment: That was very detailed and really helpful. In 2021, I find it still helpful.

Answer (score 5):

*Derived class `onCreate(bundle)` method must call superclass implementation of this method. It will throw an exception *SuperNotCalledException* if the "**super**" keyword is not used.

For inheritance in `Java`, to override the superclass method and also to execute  the above class method, use `super.methodname()` in the overriding derived class method;

Android class works in the same way. By extending the `Activity` class which have `onCreate(Bundle bundle)` method in which meaningful code is written and to execute that code in the defined activity,  use the super keyword with the method onCreate() like `super.onCreate(bundle)`.

This is a code written in Activity class `onCreate()` method and Android Dev team might add some more meaningful code to this method later. So, in order to reflect the additions, you are supposed to call the **super.onCreate()** in your `Activity` class.

```
protected void  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mVisibleFromClient = mWindow.getWindowStyle().getBoolean(
    com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowNoDisplay, true);
    mCalled = true;
}

boolean mVisibleFromClient = true;

/**
 * Controls whether this activity main window is visible.  This is intended
 * only for the special case of an activity that is not going to show a
 * UI itself, but can't just finish prior to onResume() because it needs
 * to wait for a service binding or such.  Setting this to false prevents the UI from being shown during that time.
 * 
 * <p>The default value for this is taken from the
 * {@link android.R.attr#windowNoDisplay} attribute of the activity's theme.
 */
```

It also maintains the variable `mCalled` which means you have called the `super.onCreate(savedBundleInstance)` in your Activity.

```
final void performStart() {
    mCalled = false;
    mInstrumentation.callActivityOnStart(this);
    if (!mCalled) {
        throw new SuperNotCalledException(
            "Activity " + mComponent.toShortString() +
            " did not call through to super.onStart()");
    }
}
```

See source code here.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29

Answer (score 1):

Because upon super.onCreate() it will reach the Activity (parent class of any activity) class to load the savedInstanceState,and we normaly don't set any saved instance state, but 
android framework made such a way that, we should be calling that.

Comment: Your code will compile happily even if you don't call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`, unless you have some other error in it

Answer (score 1):

It is information you want returned to your application, via onCreate(),
if the activity is destroyed and restarted due to some implicit reason
(e.g., not because the user pressed the back button). The most common
use of onSaveInstanceState() is to handle screen rotations, as by
default, activities are destroyed and recreated when the user slides out
the G1 keyboard.

The reason to call super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) is because your
code will not compile otherwise. ;-)