# SharedPreferences getting "Could not execute method of the Acitvity"

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to store user data and a password, but I always get an error "Could not execute method of the activity".

I think the write actions works:

```
Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("pref", 0).edit();
editor.putString(CustomizedListView.KEY_USER, username);
editor.putString(CustomizedListView.KEY_PASSWORD, password);
System.out.println("username: " + username);
System.out.println("password: " + password);
editor.commit();
```

I get an error with reading the preferences:

```
public class RESTClient extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> uebergabeParam = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public String getResponse(String URLParameter, HttpMethod method) {
        System.out.println("RESTClient");

        SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            // or
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String username = pref.getString(CustomizedListView.KEY_USER, "");
        String password = pref.getString(CustomizedListView.KEY_PASSWORD, "");

    try {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.addParameter(method, uebergabeParam, URLParameter, username , password);
        return client.execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("RESTClient getResponse " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println("RESTClient getResponse " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
02-22 17:37:58.903: I/System.out(1714): RESTClient
02-22 17:37:58.903: D/AndroidRuntime(1714): Shutting down VM
02-22 17:37:58.903: W/dalvikvm(1714): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412f42a0)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3691)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3686)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     ... 11 more
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at android.app.Activity.getLocalClassName(Activity.java:4556)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at android.app.Activity.getPreferences(Activity.java:4589)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at kommunikation.RESTClient.getResponse(RESTClient.java:67)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at Login.onClick(Login.java:124)
02-22 17:37:58.918: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     ... 14 more
```

Hope you can help I don't know why. Thank a lot!

**EDIT:**

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {

    // Login
    public static final String KEY_USER = "user";  
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
}
```

I edited the getReponse() method too and added the

> super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Do you have a `return` statement in the method?

Comment: post the what is written on kommunikation.RESTClient.getResponse(RESTClient.java:67).

Comment: @user2047688  what is the value of this field `CustomizedListView.KEY_PASSWORD` ?

Comment: Added the code, but the app doesn't reach following code after the `getPreferences`

Comment: @user2047688 Read my edits to the answer. The reason for the exception wasn't super.onCreate() alone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `super.onCreate()` in your `onCreate()` method.

> Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown. -[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29)

The root of that exception indicates that your activity has not yet been initialized. It has no context, and a lot of its fields are null. One of the reasons is that you're not calling `super.onCreate()`, however this would have thrown a different exception as soon as `onCreate()` returned (as the line from the doc above indicates). I suspect that you're doing something unusual like instantiating an instance of the activity using the `new` keyword and attempting to call this method which won't work as expected. You need to go through the proper channels when creating an activity. Specifically you need to call [startActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29).

Comment: When I set the `String username = "mm";` manually the Activity works fine. The problem should be really the getPreferences

Comment: Yes, that's because setting the string doesn't require a context. Getting preferences requires a valid context, and your activity isn't a valid context unless you use the channels that Android expects.

Answer (score 0):

Read from below link why is necessary to call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

[super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671897/super-oncreatesavedinstancestate/14671970#14671970)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Read saved data from `sharedPreference` like this

```
public String getResponse(String URLParameter, HttpMethod method) {

    SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String username = pref.getString(CustomizedListView.KEY_USER, "");
    String password = pref.getString(CustomizedListView.KEY_PASSWORD, "");

        ...
}
```

I think NPE might username or password have null value. Check it using Debug.

```
editor.putString(CustomizedListView.KEY_USER, username);
editor.putString(CustomizedListView.KEY_PASSWORD, password);
```

Comment: @user2047688 what is written on kommunikation.RESTClient.getResponse(RESTClient.java:67)

Comment: Yes, I added the whole code and trials.
`getPreferences("password", MODE_PRIVATE);` doesn't work with the first String statement

Comment: @user2047688 you have not initialize the uebergabeParam.

Comment: @user2047688 Debug you application some object have NPE and you are trying to access it If not solve let me know as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

what i can see in your code is that you are mixing methods `getPreferences()` and `getSharedPreferences()`, the second one is when you have diferent files of preferences. im not sure if this will cause the aplication to crash.

if your are working with only 1 preferences file avoid using the method `getSharedPreferences()` if you do have more than 1 preferences files you must specify at compile time wich file you are refering to.

final edit:

you are calling SharedPreferences from a method that does not have a `Context`:

```
public String getResponse(String URLParameter, HttpMethod method){

   SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);

}
```

as long as its on a `Activity` use this:

```
public String getResponse(String URLParameter, HttpMethod method){

       SharedPreferences pref = getAplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);

    }
```

Comment: like the rest of the guys pointed out you also need to call  `super.onCreate`

Comment: I did, but I have still this problem, when I set the username and password manually hardcoded I don't get this error.