# pubnub duplicate messages android

Tags: android, pubnub

I was hoping someone may be able to help or at least point me in the right direction.  I'm writing an android app that publishes/receives messages and i'm trying to use PubNub to accomplish this task.  In my view I firstly unsubscribe from a group name and then subscribe to it.  When I then publish a message, I successfully get one message.  If I then leave the view and re-enter it, when I publish a message I get a duplicate.  If I do the same again, the message is triplicated and so on.

Could someone please look at my code or give me any advice.

Many thanks.

```
private Pubnub pubnub =  new Pubnub("pub-key", "sub-key");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.rickeshjobanputra.snapapp.R.layout.activity_group);

    GroupName = intent.getStringExtra("GroupName");

    String uuid = "12345";
    pubnub.setUUID(uuid);
    pubnub.unsubscribe(GroupName);

    try {
        pubnub.subscribe(GroupName, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void successCallback(String channel, final Object message) {
                System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : "
                        + message.getClass() + " : " + message.toString());
            }
        });
    } catch (PubnubException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    addListenerOnButton();
}

private void addListenerOnButton() {
    final Context context = this;
    button = (Button) findViewById(com.rickeshjobanputra.snapapp.R.id.snap_something_button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pubnub.publish(GroupName, "test", new Callback() {
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    pubnub.unsubscribeAllChannels();

    try {
        pubnub.subscribe("test", new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void connectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                pubnub.publish("test", "Hello from the PubNub Java SDK", new Callback() {});
            }

            @Override
            public void successCallback(String channel, final Object message) {
                System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : "
                        + message.getClass() + " : " + message.toString());
            }
        });
    } catch (PubnubException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is happening in here: ```super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);``` And I suspect maybe this ```addListenerOnButton()``` is getting called each time but not removing the listener from the previous iteration. You might want to have the listener check to see if it is alreayd *listening*. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Craig thanks for the response.  See [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671897/super-oncreatesavedinstancestate for why we need `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`  I removed the listener even though it just handles the onclik event.  I updated my code as shown above but the same thing happens.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I understand the use of super, I was just wondering if there was any code in the super class that you had implemented or if it is an Android framework class (assume the latter - if so, no worries). But what class are you extending?

Comment: Is the code in the first box a Fragment or Activity? If its a fragment, are you creating multiple instances of your fragment?

Comment: Hi the code is an activity and it extends `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Hi guys, I managed to get it to work!  Frederick you were right that I was instantiated a local variable of Pubnub,  I moved this declaration to a class that `extends Application` and now it works perfectly.  I subscribe to one channel and only one message gets published.  Thank you both for your help.  It was really appreciated!

Comment: Beautiful! Fred will update with official answer soon. Please accept it as accepted answer when he does so. Cheers.

Comment: Can you please help i am facing same problem