# What usage does savedInstanceState have in super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)?

Tags: android, android-activity

So, I am trying to understand the inner workings of Android and I haven't found an in depth explanation of what I am looking for. For my simple program:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

What is the difference in using `null` instead of `savedInstanceState` in `super.onCreate()`? I have tried both and there was no difference for my program.

If there is a difference, in which ways will the usage of `savedInstanceState` affect my program, as opposed to using `null`?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671897/super-oncreatesavedinstancestate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked question/answer in @sasikumar's comment is good, and answers why you must call `super.onCreate()`, but it does not answer why you must pass the `Bundle savedInstanceState` parameter to the super call (as opposed to a `new Bundle()` or `null`).

The simple answer is that the `savedInstanceState` bundle contains information recorded **by the Android framework** that the super method will then use to restore state. For instance, any `EditText` with an `android:id` attribute will automatically save whatever the user has typed into it, and that information will be inside the `savedInstanceState` bundle. If you pass null, this automatic restoration is impossible.

Note that the `savedInstanceState` parameter will actually **be** `null` the very first time your activity is created. It will only be non-null when your activity has been destroyed and re-created (usually in response to a configuration change like the rotation of your phone, but there are many other scenarios as well).

### Update

My example of automatic state restoration was incorrect. The `EditText` automatic restoration happens in the `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` callback, not in `onCreate`. Unfortunately, you can't simply pass `null` to that super method to see what happens (your app will crash).

However, this example will show what I meant. Assume your `activity_main` has some `FrameLayout` with an id of `@+id/content`, and assume you have some `Fragment` subclass that displays *anything* visible to the user. Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.content, new MyFragment(), "MyFragment")
                .commit();
    }
}
```

As is, this will display your fragment on first launch, and will continue to display the fragment after you rotate your device back and forth. This is because the `FragmentManager` uses the `savedInstanceState` bundle to save/restore fragments, and **that** is done in `super.onCreate`.

If you change the super call to `super.onCreate(null)`, you'll still see the fragment the first time your activity starts up (since we're manually adding it at that point). But if you rotate the device, the fragment will disappear.

Comment: I understand the difference in using/not using the android:id for the state restoration in the case of filling a EditText. But, when i still pass null to the super.onCreate(), my application is still able to automatic restore. In this case I still can't find the difference.

Comment: @Vlad I've updated my answer to address your question

Comment: Thank you very much @Ben P. Your second response really clarified my situation.